# Is it possible to use asynchronous receiver for unknown number of received bytes?

Tags: c#, sockets, asynchronous

My app is built on C# synchronous sockets, and I am trying to replace them with asynchronous ones, in order to improve efficiency (if possible). So far, I have replaced on the server the Send() and Accept() with the asynchronous ones (based on the MSDN documents), but I have some issues to implement the Receive().

**Original (synchronous):**

```
Socket _socket = new Socket(SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
bool _flag = true;
CheckFun()
{
   while (_flag)
   {
      Thread.Sleep(10); // every ~10ms check
      byte[] _buffer;
      if (_socket.Available != 0)
      {
          _buffer = new byte[1]; // just check 1st byte
          _socket.Receive(_buffer, 1, SocketFlags.None);
          if (_buffer[0] == 1)
          {
              ReceiveFun();
          }
      }
   }
}

ReceiveFun()
{    
   int hdrSize = 12;
   byte[] buffer = new byte[hdrSize];   
   _socket.Receive(buffer, hdrSize, SocketFlags.None);
   int _dataLength = buffer[0]; // the 1st byte has already been removed before calling the ReceiveFun()
   buffer = new byte[_dataLength]; 
   int _bytesRead = 0;
   while (_bytesRead != _dataLength)
   {
        while (_socket.Available == 0)
        {
             if (!_socket.Connected)
                 return 0;
        }
        _bytesRead += _socket.Receive(buffer, _bytesRead, _dataLength - _bytesRead, SocketFlags.None);
   }
   //read bytes blah blah...
}
```

My question is how to turn this operation into an asynchronous one and concatenate the bytes received until I receive all information? And then again wait for the next one?

**EDIT**

**Async**

```
public class State
{
    public int nToReadBytes = 0;
    public int nBytesRead = 0;
    public const int BufferSize = 1024;         
    public byte[] buffer = new byte[BufferSize];     // Receive buffer.     
}

List<byte> lReceivedBytes = new List<byte>();
int hdrSize = 12;
public void ReadCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
{
     // Retrieve the state object and the handler socket  
    // from the asynchronous state object.  
    var state = ar.AsyncState as State;  

   // Read data from the client socket.   
   int availableBytes = oSocket.EndReceive(ar);

   if (availableBytes > 0)
   {
       if (lReceivedBytes.Count == 0)
       {
            if (state.buffer[0] == 1)
            { 
                 // the first field of the header has been successfully decoded
                 if (availableBytes > 1)
                 {
                     state.nToReadBytes = BitConverter.ToInt32(state.buffer, 1) + hdrSize;
                     int _bytesCopy = Math.Min(state.nToReadBytes, state.buffer.Length); //in case that the data is less than the State.BufferSize (unlikely)
                     state.nBytesRead += _bytesCopy;
                     lReceivedBytes.AddRange(state.buffer);
                 }
            }  
            else if (state.buffer[0] == 2)
            { 
                 // the first field of the header has been successfully decoded but do nothing!
                 _socket.BeginReceive(state.buffer, 0, State.BufferSize, 0, new AsyncCallback(ReadCallback), state);
                 return;
            }  
            else
                throw new InvalidDataException("Invalid hdr field [1-2]: " + state.buffer[0]);  
       }
       else
       {
            state.nBytesRead += state.buffer.Length;
            lReceivedBytes.AddRange(state.buffer);         
       }

       if (lReceivedBytes.Count == state.nToReadBytes)
       { 
           //read all information and clear list and States in the end (?)
           //   ...
           lReceivedBytes.Clear();
           state.nToReadBytes = 0;
           state.nBytesRead = 0;
           _socket.BeginReceive(state.buffer, 0, State.BufferSize, 0, new AsyncCallback(ReadCallback), state);
       }
       else
       {
            //int _newSize = Math.Min(state.nToReadBytes - state.nBytesRead, State.BufferSize); // for restriction (?)      
            int _newSize = state.nToReadBytes - state.nBytesRead; // for now don't check 
            _socket.BeginReceive(state.buffer, 0, _newSize, 0, new AsyncCallback(ReadCallback), state); //shall I increase the size (it could be between 90 kB - 170kB, until all info is received)
       }
    }
    else
       _socket.BeginReceive(state.buffer, 0, State.BufferSize, 0, new AsyncCallback(ReadCallback), state);
 }
```

Comment: Have you tried using [`ReceiveAsync()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.socket.receiveasync) instead of `Receive()`?

Comment: @GabrielLuci I tried with the BeginReceive() and EndReceive()

Comment: That would work too. What went wrong when you tried that? (if you're already comfortable using `async`/`await`, this article shows how you can make an awaitable `ReceiveAsync`: [Awaiting Socket Operations](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/pfxteam/awaiting-socket-operations/))

Comment: The EndReceive is needed to allow another Asynchronous message to be received.  There is no guarantee with TCP that all the data byte sent are received in the same asynchronous event.  So you each message need to have a know END OF MESSAGE indicator which is either a byte count at the beginning of message or a terminating character at end of message.

Comment: @GabrielLuci I was using the int bytesAvailable = Socket.EndReceive(ar); to determine whether there were bytes. I could successfully parse the first "chunk" and read the header information, but not for the rest parses. I will edit and will include this.

Comment: @jdweng I was trying to use a field on the header I use to indicate the length of the frame. The server would read and append the data until the end of _length_, then read the frame and wait for the next one

Comment: If you are appending it is better to use a List<byte>

Comment: @jdweng I used a List<byte> to append them, but it's not correctly read after the 1st read. I will update the question with what I have done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Socket` class has two main asynchronous paradigms: the original callback-based Asynchronous Programming Model (APM) and the only-slightly-newed Event-based Asynchronous Pattern (EAP). Both of these can be somewhat unwieldy to implement as compared to the synchronous appproach, as they require you to adjust your thinking to connection *state* instead of just *local* method logic, breaking up what would be a single method into parts dealing with the initiation and completion of the operation.

Fortunately, the newer Task Parallel Library model leverages `async` and `await` to allow asynchronous code to be written in almost identical fashion to the equivalent synchronous version. For the `Socket` class, to take advantage of this, you need to wrap its asynchronous API in a TPL-compatible way. .NET does provide a general-purpose way to take existing APM APIs and wrap them in tasks (see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/tpl-and-traditional-async-programming), but IMHO it is simpler to take advantage of the `NetworkStream` class, which wraps a socket in a `Stream` object.

Since `Stream` already has received the "TPL love", i.e. has `ReceiveAsync()` and similar methods to allow TPL-based operations, I find this somewhat easier than dealing with the wrapper methods designed to map APM to TPL.

In your code, that would wind up looking something like this:

```cs
// Somewhere appropriate -- your code example isn't specific or complete enough
// to offer anything more detailed than this
NetworkStream _stream = new NetworkStream(_socket);

async Task ReceiveFun()
{    
    int _bytesRead = 0, hdrSize = 12;
    byte[] buffer = new byte[hdrSize];

    while (_bytesRead < hdrSize)
    {
        int bytesRead = await _stream.ReadAsync(buffer, _bytesRead, hdrSize - _bytesRead);

        if (bytesRead == 0) throw new InvalidDataException("unexpected end-of-stream");
        _bytesRead += bytesRead;
    }

    int _dataLength = buffer[0]; // the 1st byte has already been removed before calling the ReceiveFun()
    buffer = new byte[_dataLength]; 

    _bytesRead = 0;
    while (_bytesRead < _dataLength)
    {
        int bytesRead = await _stream.ReadAsync(buffer, _bytesRead, _dataLength - _bytesRead);

        if (bytesRead == 0) throw new InvalidDataException("unexpected end-of-stream");
        _bytesRead += bytesRead;
   }
   //read bytes blah blah...
}
```

Note that your original synchronous code had a bug: you were not using the returned byte count when reading the header, and so had no way to know if the full header was actually being returned in a single call or not. You *must* always look at the count of bytes read; this can always be as few as 1 when data is available, and of course will be 0 when the end of stream is reached (i.e. the remote endpoint uses the *shutdown* operation).

Your code also did not check for end-of-stream correctly. Just look at the bytes returned when you try to read from the socket. I've fixed that in the above as well.

Comment: What is the totalBytes? ReadAsync looks "similar" to the original implementation, meaning that it does not require major modifications. Based on my understanding, I should use an infinite loop to somehow schedule the task, right? Further, would it cause any issues since the Send() and Accept() are based on the states?

Comment: _"What is the totalBytes?"_ -- sorry, typo left over from original construction of code. Fixed it. _"I should use an infinite loop to somehow schedule the task, right?"_ -- impossible to say without a [mcve] in your question. But, typically when accepting the connection, you would  call the async method that is supposed to handle that connection. The returned `Task` object would represent the connection state, with the method completing and causing the `Task` object to be completed when the connection is closed.

Comment: _"would it cause any issues since the Send() and Accept() are based on the states?"_ -- impossible to say, since you haven't provided enough context. But it should not be any different from handling of states in the synchronous approach.

Comment: I have edited my question by including the CheckFun() where it shows how the ReceiveFun() used to be called. One thread dedicated only for reading from the stream, where every _X_ ms, I was checking whether there was anything to be read. ReadAsync() should be called in the same way?

Comment: _"would it cause any issues since the Send() and Accept() are based on the states?"_ -- What I mean is that I used the following `_socket.BeginSend(buffer, 0, buffer.Length, 0,  new AsyncCallback(SendCallback), _socket);` where the `SendCallback() { Socket client = (Socket) ar.AsyncState; int bytesSent = client.EndSend(ar);}`

Comment: _"every X ms, I was checking whether there was anything to be read"_ -- your original code was defective. It's bad enough to use the "select" socket model involving polling a socket in a single thread. But if you've dedicated a thread to each connection, there is simply _no reason at all_ to do anything except call `Receive()` and wait for data, blocking the thread. The thread's already not being used for anything else, so stop waking it up periodically just to check for a condition that the network driver would otherwise wake the thread up automatically for anyway.

Comment: In any case, if you follow the asynchronous strategy using `await`, this is all simplified even further, without dedicating a thread to the connection. My previous responses still apply.

Comment: Is it possible to call/initiate the task from a non async method (`private void AcceptCallback(IAsyncResult ar)`) though?

Comment: You can mix/match as you like, yes. Note that while `Socket` does not have a TPL-compatible API, you can use `TaskFactory.FromAsync()` to wrap the `Begin`/`End` APM-style methods in a task object. So even your accept logic can be done using TPL-style code.